# Obtener ubicación nada más entrar en la aplicación

Tags: flutter

Buenas tardes es la primera vez que estoy trabajando con flutter para hacer una aplicación, dicha aplicación su primera vista es un mapa donde tiene que marcar la ubicación actual que tiene el usuario. Con google maps ya he hecho que cuando carga la primera vista solicite permisos para poder acceder a la ubicación de su teléfono.

Pero lo que necesito tal cual se haga esa pregunta, si acepta ya automáticamente se ponga en el mapa sin necesidad de pulsar un botón de obtener ubicación.

Tengo esto realizado y me pregunto si yo ya realizo la pregunta de acceder a la ubicación nada más arrancar ya podría acceder a `await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();` ??

**Mi código:**

```
class CurrentLocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CurrentLocationScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CurrentLocationScreenState createState() => _CurrentLocationScreenState();
}

class _CurrentLocationScreenState extends State<CurrentLocationScreen> {
  late GoogleMapController googleMapController;

  static const CameraPosition initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962), zoom: 14);

  Set<Marker> markers = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition,
        markers: markers,
        zoomControlsEnabled: false,
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          googleMapController = controller;
        },
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: false
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () async {
          Position position = await _determinePosition();

          googleMapController
              .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude), zoom: 14)));


          markers.clear();

          markers.add(Marker(markerId: const MarkerId('currentLocation'),position: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude)));

          setState(() {});

        },
        label: const Text("Current Location"),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.location_history),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();

    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled');
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();

      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error("Location permission denied");
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error('Location permissions are permanently denied');
    }

    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();

    return position;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcto, en la propiedad `onMapCreated` tu puedes llamar a la función `_determinePosition` y después lo que tienes en el botón flotante lo puedes pasar directamente en el `onMapCreated`:

```
onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
      googleMapController = controller;
      final position = await _determinePosition();
      if(position != null){
         googleMapController
          .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude), zoom: 14)));


      markers.clear();

      markers.add(Marker(markerId: const MarkerId('currentLocation'),position: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude)));

      setState(() {});
      }
    },
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto! genial muchas gracias. Te hago una pregunta más, porque no sale mi ubicación real? da igual que entre en mi app o en la app de mapas de iphone que sale San francisco

Comment: Si estás en mac, posiblemente sea el emulador de dispositivos, la app del emulador de ios te permite poner una ubicación estática para empezar tienes que ir a: FEATURES => LOCATION => CUSTOM LOCATION y ahí puedes personalizar la ubicación, pero solo es en el caso del emulador, prueba con un dispositivo físico

Comment: Puedo probar la aplicación que estoy haciendo con un dispositivo físico?? enserio? no lo sabia... como como....

Comment: Si tienes android tienes que activar las opciones de desarrollador de en la configuración y en el caso de IOs solo tienes que conectar tu dispositivo, creo, yo trabajo con android y para hacer las pruebas en ios si uso el emulador

Comment: Osea desde Android Studio puedo conectar mi iphone y ver la aplicación?

Comment: debería, yo trabajo con visual studio, pero prueba, o si no, puedes compilarla desde xcode: WINDOW => DEVICES AND SIMULATORS => seleccionas tu dispositivo y la instalas, esta ultima opción solo te permite ver el resultado final de la app, no puedes ver los cambios en ejecución

Comment: ok ok, lo acabo de probar, es cierto que sale para seleccionar mi iphone pero necesito unos certificados, gracias por la ayuda